# Debounced input sending repeated values

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

So I have a custom async validator like so:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
    import { DefaultApi } from "../data/api/DefaultApi";
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import 'rxjs/Rx';

    @Injectable()
    export class ValidationService {

    tempURL = "http://localhost/api/v1/validate";

    oldVal: any;

    constructor(private defaultApi: DefaultApi) {
    }

    generateValidator(validationType: string) {
        return (control: FormControl) => {
        return new Observable((obs: any) => {
            control
            .valueChanges
            .debounceTime(400)
            .mergeMap(value => {
                return this.defaultApi.validationGet(validationType, value)
            })
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                obs.next(null);
                obs.complete();
                },
                error => {
                obs.next({'validationFailed': true});
                obs.complete();
                }
            );
        }).distinctUntilChanged();


        }

    }
    }
```

The issue is that while it is 'grouping' the keystrokes correctly (ie someone types 913 it emits 913 not 9 1 3) it is emitting them multiple times(913, 913, 913). I have tried moving the distinctUntilChanged around but to no avail. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Try `.throttleTime(400)` instead of `.debounceTime(400)`.

Comment: That gets rid of the duplicate requests however it doesn't seem to add any delay. This is to validate an input field so I want to wait for the user to stop typing for a bit before I hit the server.

Comment: You might have to set a timeout before starting the observable, but debounce will always have the same inputs as outputs just spaced out (ie someone types 1-2-3 it will emit 3 times) where as throttle with limit or filter the outputs.